# Can't disable WinHttpAutoProxySvc

Tags: amazon-web-services, service, windows-server-2019

The WinHttpAutoProxySvc is disabled in Services on Windows Server 2019.

Is it safe to disable it and if it does, how to do it?

I'm running into this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63601757/https-outbound-requests-time-increases-to-5-min-after-14-21-days-on-an-instance

This service brokes every 2-4 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

No, the WinHttpAutoProxySvc should not be disabled. When a service controls are dimmed like that, it is an indication it should not be modified. It would be preferable to pursue the root cause of the issue.

As a last resort, it may be disabled by changing the following registry value:

```
Key: HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinHttpAutoProxySvc  
Value: Start  
Value Data: 4
```

With regards to safety, that would need to be determined by testing in your environment.

[Can I safely disable WinHttpAutoProxySvc if I don't have a proxy?](https://serverfault.com/questions/112218/can-i-safely-disable-winhttpautoproxysvc-if-i-dont-have-a-proxy)

https://serverfault.com/a/762987/20701

Many organizations have disabled this functionality due to critical security vulnerabilities, and no-one needs it anyway. Typically this involves using the Microsoft recommended method by adding `255.255.255.255 WPAD` to the hosts file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/securitybulletins/2016/ms16-077#workarounds